# String substitution in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Using this initialization statement:

```javascript
  var str = $('#res').text();
```

this gives :

```
Details are below 1. Payables 2. Purchasing 3. Cash Management
```

I want to put line break `<br>` before each number so that the page looks like

```
Details are below 

1. Payables 
2. Purchasing 
3. Cash Management
```

I tried :

```javascript
str.replace(/[^d.,]+/,'<br>');
```

But it is not working as expected.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `'Details are below 1. Payables 2. Purchasing 3. Cash Management'.replace(/\d+\./g, function(m) => { return '<br>' + m; });`?

Comment: I tried with it in console and getting `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '=>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression and replacements

```js
$('#res').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<br />$1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res">Details are below 1. Payables 2. Purchasing 3. Cash Management</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="abc">Details are below 1. Payables 2. Purchasing 3. Cash Management</div>
<div id="cd"></div>
<script>
var ab = $("#abc").text();
var cd = ab.replace(/(\d+)/g,"<br/> $1");
$("#cd").html(cd);

</script>
```